# python3 value returned wrong with container variable

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I meet a code that failed to meet my expectation. Details as below:

```
    a = ['name']
    b = [('name=cheng',),('name=huang',),('name=pan',)]
    Dict = {}
    c = []
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,1):
            Dict[a[j]] = b[i][j]
            c.append(Dict)
    print(c)

>>> [{'name':'name=pan'},{'name':'name=pan'},{'name':'name=pan'}]
```

what `i` expected should be

```
>>> [{'name':'name=cheng'},{'name':'name=huang'},{'name':'name=pan'}]
```

So could you please tell me how to solve the issue ?

Comment: What is `Dict`?

Comment: sorry for my fault , code updated . thanks!

Comment: Dont you mean `print(c)` to produce that output? You're overriding the values stored with `Dict[a[j]] = ...`  since `a[j]` always returns `'name'`. Just do `c.append({a[j]: b[i][j]})` instead.

Comment: yes, it is ..sorry.

Comment: Don't use `Dict` as a variable name. Though valid, `dict` is reserved and you should not have two variables where the only difference is a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same value of `Dict` for all of the iterations of the loop. So all of the dictionaries are the same. You just have three copies of the same dictionary in the list.

If you move the `Dict = {}` statement into the loop, it will be fixed.

```
a = ['name']
b = [('name=cheng',),('name=huang',),('name=pan',)]
c = []
for i in range(0,3):
    Dict = {}
    for j in range(0,1):
        Dict[a[j]] = b[i][j]
        c.append(Dict)
print(c)
```

Or more Pythonic:

```
keys = ['name']
values_list = [('name=cheng',), ('name=huang',), ('name=pan',)]

result = []

for values in values_list:
    result.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))

print(result)
```

This works by using the `zip` builtin which does the same thing as `[(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(min(len(x), len(y))]` without needing to keep track of the indices or lengths.

The `dict` class can build a dictionary from a list of tuples, which is what this solution uses.

Comment: great , in your Pythonic answer , since `value_list` is a `list` contains `tuple` other than single element , So only 1 `for ` loop is not enough to iteration . just a kind reminder. thanks!

Comment: @huangcheng that was because I used `zip`, which does iteration itself.

Answer (score 5):

You are changing the value of `Dict` **in place** and not creating a new dictionary every time. Each iteration of the loop, you are setting `Dict["name"]` equal to one of the elements in `b` and then appending it to the list. The next iteration of your loop changes dict in place (meaning the previous version you appending to c will also be changed). The result is that your list `c` is filled with 3 exact copies (exact same location in memory) of the dictionary created in the final iteration of the loop.

How do you fix this? Make a new dictionary every time.

```py
a = ['name']
b = [('name=cheng',),('name=huang',),('name=pan',)]
c = []
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,1):
        temp_dict = {a[j]: b[i][j]} 
        c.append(temp_dict)
print(c)
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'name=cheng'}, {'name': 'name=huang'}, {'name': 'name=pan'}]
```

Comment: +1 - in fact the list `c` has 3 references to the _same_ dictionary. If you update `Dict['name'] = ...` then all 3 update.